# Poisson's laws for adiabatic processes

Tags: physics, terminology, thermodynamics

I've been reading about Thermodynamics lately. The set of equations satisfied in an adiabatic process (and also more generally in polytropic ones) is:

$$p_1V_1^\gamma = p_2V_2^\gamma$$
$$T_1V_1^{\gamma-1} = T_2V_2^{\gamma-1}$$
$$T_1^\gamma p_1^{1-\gamma} = T_2^\gamma p_2^{1-\gamma}$$

I've seen these called *Poisson's equations* or *Poisson's laws*, but I was able to find no information about the naming. Did [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sim%C3%A9on_Denis_Poisson) really derive/talk about these relations, or is it just a misnomer? Maybe another person sharing the same last name? Thanks!

**Edit:** I now know that Poisson first used $\gamma$ for "condensation", which will later become the heat capacity ratio used above. However, I still don't know if he treated those equations or who first named them after him.